# How many people joined the ICO?

Tags: distribution

I know they spent all IOTA coins for 500.000$. And everyone had to buy the coins with their own money. But how many people participated in the initial coin offering?

Comment: Why so many votes to close the question? Why is token distribution not relevant? Maybe you could also answer this question if you vote to close https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/607

Comment: I don't get it either. I think token distribution is very relevant to the community. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

To my understanding, the question of how many people joined the ICO is hard to answer. Due to the fact that one person can have multiple addresses, I haven’t found any „official“ source giving out numbers of „people“. But you find a lot about existing addresses with a positive balance. Maybe that will partially answer your question. There are really well-written and worth reading articles about the distribution of IOTA on medium. For example here: [IOTA Distribution: Update after Snapshot from 08th August 2017](https://medium.com/@IngoFiedler_96862/iota-distribution-update-after-snapshot-from-08th-august-2017-21e92cf15eea)

Comment: But with the number of addresses, there is kind of an upper bound. Do you know where early snapshots of the tangle can be found?

Comment: IOTA ICO/Crowdsale took place here:https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1262688.0  The ICO Adress ( https://blockchain.info/address/1G8hh3bHMMhZSATwisBVbGFSYBKK3Suib8 ) recieved 663 transactions.

Comment: Pre-snapshot dbs can be found here for example: http://store.alon-e.com/IOTA_DBs/